# Metric relabel configs in Promtheus not working as expected

Tags: prometheus

recently I'm trying to drop some metrics since prometheus usage is getting way too much than I expected.

```
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__name__]
    separator: ;
    regex: (istio_requests_total)
    replacement: $1
    action: drop
```

But I tried this fairly straight forward metric_relabel_configs, "istio_requests_total" doesn't drop as expected. I know you may ask why I don't drop this in relabeling.

My very first goal is to drop all the metrics with destination_service = unknown associated with istio like :

```
  - source_labels: [destination_service]
    separator: ;
    regex: ^unknown(.*)
    replacement: $1
    action: drop
```

This doens't work ,so I go back to a simple "metric" drop see if this can work. Anyways let me know if I made anything wrong and thank you all in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The following relabeling rule should drop all the metrics with `istio_requests_total` name:

```yaml
- action: drop
  source_labels: [__name__]
  regex: istio_requests_total
```

If you need dropping all the metrics with the `destination_service` label, which starts from `unknown` prefix, then use the following relabeling rule:

```yaml
- action: drop
  source_labels: [destination_service]
  regex: "unknown.*"
```

This relabeling rule must be placed in the `metric_relabel_configs` section under the [scrape_configs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs.html#scrape_configs), which are responsible for scraping the istio target.

P.S. You can debug Prometheus metric relabeling [here](https://play.victoriametrics.com/select/accounting/1/6a716b0f-38bc-4856-90ce-448fd713e3fe/metric-relabel-debug).